# Вызвано исключение: нарушение доступа для чтения. this->

Tags: c++

У меня класс Студент и класс Группа, который содержит массив объектов Студент.
Не могу решить проблему. Почитала информацию по этому поводу, к сожалению так и не поняла.

```
class Group {
    Student** students;
    unsigned int group_size;
    int course;
public:
    Group();
    Group(Student* _students[], unsigned int _group_size, int __course);
    Group(const Group& other);
    ~Group();
    void AddStudent();
    void showInfo();
};

Group::Group() : students(nullptr), group_size(1), course(1) {};
Group::Group(Student* _students[], unsigned int _group_size, int _course) {
    students = new Student * [_group_size];
    for (int i = 0; i < _group_size; i++) {
        students[i] = _students[i];
    }
    this->group_size = _group_size;
    this->course = _course;
}
Group::~Group() {
    for (int i = 0; i < group_size; i++) {
        delete students[i];
    }

    delete[] students;
}
Group::Group(const Group& other) {
    for (int i = 0; i < other.group_size; i++)
    {
        students[i] = new Student(*other.students[i]);
    }
    group_size = other.group_size;
    course = other.course;
}

void Group::AddStudent() {

    Student** st = new Student * [this->group_size + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < this->group_size + 1; i++)
    {
        st[i] = this->students[i];
    }
    delete[] this->students;
    this->students = st;
    students[this->group_size]->Student::enterInfo();
    this->group_size++;
}
void Group::showInfo() {

    if (group_size > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < group_size; i++)
        {
            cout << "Student - " << i + 1;
            students[i]->showInfo();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Group is empty!!\n";
    }
}
```

[image: 210 строка]

Comment: Вы неправильно объявили указатель в классе. Судя по тому, что вы в дальнейшем выделяете память под одмерный массив, должно быть `class Group { Student* students;` И конструктор `Group::Group(Student _students[],`

Comment: посмотрите на строку, где ругается отладчик.  И подумайте, о размере массива students и что будет, когда в цикле будет i = this->group_size (подсказка - выход за пределы).

Comment: Определитесь, что вы хотите видеть под указателем `students`. Это Указатель на массив указателей или указатель на массив объектов? Просто в одном месте вы работаете как с 1 вариантом, а в другом - как со вторым.

Comment: @DmitryK,  я хочу создать указатель на массив объектов

Comment: Тогда должно быть так `class Group { Student* students;`. И в этом случае деструктор неправильный - цикл с `delete` не нужен и в здесь тоже ошибка `AddStudent() { Student* st = new `

Comment: @DmitryK, подскажите, пожалуйста.  Если у меня есть класс Группа, в котором указатель на массив объектов класса Студент. И информацию о студенте я заполняю с консоли, то я же правильно поняла, что в этом случае мне нужен указатель на массив объектов? Мне нужно, чтобы в класс Группа создавал массив объектов Студент.

Comment: Да, правильно. Вам нужен просто указатель, на который Вы выделяете память под массив объектов `Student* students = new Student[_group_size];`

Answer (score 0):

Если указатель `students` в классе это указатель на массив объектов класса `Student`, то должно быть так:

```
class Group 
{
    Student* students; // один указатель, а не указатель на указатель
```

Конструктор по-умолчанию с ошибкой. Указатель `nullptr` а размер группы Вы почему-то инициализируете 1? Как будто у вас там 1 студент есть!

```
Group::Group() : students(nullptr), group_size(1), course(1) {};
```

Поскольку мы не видим класса `Student` здесь возможна ошибка - присваивание структуры структуре будет работать правильно только если она состоит из тривиальных типов, или если вы перегрузили `operator=()`

```
Group::Group(Student* _students[], unsigned int _group_size, int _course) {
    students = new Student[_group_size];
    for (int i = 0; i < _group_size; i++) 
        students[i] = _students[i];  // вот здесь возможна ошибка
```

Деструктор неправильный. Он написан под указатель на массив указателей. В в нем удаляете память, которую не выделяли.

```
Group::~Group() {
//    for (int i = 0; i < group_size; i++)   // вот этого быть не должно
//        delete students[i];
    
    delete[] students;
}
```

Конструктор копирования `Group::Group(const Group& other)` тоже с ошибками. Вы тут динамически выделяете память под каждый объект `Student`, а надо:

- проверить указатель, если массив уже выделен - удалить
- выделить память под новое количество элементов
- переприсвоить элементы

Ну и добавление - опять выделение памяти под массив указателей. А потом работа как с массивом объектов.

```
void Group::AddStudent() 
{
    Student* st = new Student[this->group_size + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < this->group_size + 1; i++)
        st[i] = this->students[i];

    delete[] this->students;
    this->students = st;
    students[this->group_size]->Student::enterInfo();
    this->group_size++;
}
```

Если путаетесь в динамических выделениях памяти, то проще всего использовать динамический массив из стандартной библиотеки `class Group { vector<Student> students;`
Или хотя бы используйте умные указатели для работы с памятью `std::unique_ptr<Student>`

Comment: огромное Вам спасибо! Что-то и в правду запуталась с указателями, попробую сейчас с вектором. Думаю, будет немного проще)

Comment: Будет намного проще! :) Вы вообще не будете заниматься выделением/удалением памяти.